# Im trying to convert expression infix to postfix,why i'm getting output null insted ab-?

Tags: c, null, infix-notation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
}; 
    
int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
} 
    
int isFull(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
    
int push(struct stack *ptr, int val) {
    if (isFull(ptr))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }

    return 1; 
}

int pop(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top--;
        int val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        return val;
    } 
}

int stackTop(struct stack *ptr) {
    return ptr->arr[ptr->top];
}

int precedence(char ch) {
    if (ch == '/' || ch == '*')
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isOperand(char ch) {
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    } 
}

char IntoPostFix(char *Infix) {
    struct stack *s = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->top = -1;
    s->size = 100;
    s->arr = (char *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(char));
    char *postfix = (char *)malloc(strlen(Infix + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0; //value at intfix;
    int j = 0; //store into post fix
    while (Infix[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (!isOperand(Infix[i]))
        {
            postfix[j] = Infix[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (precedence(Infix[i]) > precedence(stackTop(s)))
            {
                push(s, Infix[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                postfix[j] = pop(s);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (!isEmpty(s))
    {
        postfix[j] = pop(s);
        j++;
    }
    postfix[j] = '\0';
    return postfix[j]; 
} 

int main() {
    char *Infix = "a-b";
    printf("PostFix is : %s\n ", IntoPostFix(Infix));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note the compiler warning: *'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'*, which is from the last `printf()`. Actually `char` but `char` is promoted to `int` for a variadic function. Try changing `%s` to `%c` to match the type.

Answer (score 0):

You format string expects a string but you give it a char:

```
printf("PostFix is : %s\n ", IntoPostFix(Infix));
```

Change the signature and return postfix instead of the '\0':

```
char *IntoPostFix(char *Infix) {
...
   return postfix;
}
```

It now prints "ab\n ", that is, we correctly process 'a', 'b', and '-' is pushed on the stack.  `pop(s)` return 0 you decrement top before you return the value:

```
ptr->top--;
int val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
return val;
```

instead do:

```
return ptr->arr[ptr->top--];
```

and voila:

```
PostFix is : ab-
```

Bonus round:

1. In IntoPostFix you call `malloc()` 3 times and don't call `free()` so your program leaks memory.
2. Instead of `strlen(Infix + 1)` which evaluates to `strlen(Infix) - 1` you want `strlen(Infix) + 1`.
3. Instead of `while (Infix[i] != '\0')` consider using a for() loop to reduce the scope of the variable i.  Avoid negation and use continue for less branching noise. If you use this style of compressing newlines you get about twice as much code on the screen at a time:

```
for(int i = 0; Infix[i]; ) {
    if(isOperand(Infix[i])) {
        if(precedence(Infix[i]) > precedence(stackTop(s))) {
            push(s, Infix[i++]);
        } else {
            postfix[j++] = pop(s);
        }
        continue;
     }
     postfix[j++] = Infix[i++];
}
```